# Rails generate options with classes based on parent for jQuery conditional hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a couple of forms that have select boxes that I would like to conditionally hide the options based on previous options selected. For example:

On the sign up page I have 2 select boxes, agency and branch. The agency select is generated using

```
<%= f.select(:agency_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Agency.all, :id, :name), prompt: 'Select your Agency') %>
```

and the branch one:

```
<%= f.select(:branch_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Branch.all, :id, :name), prompt: 'Select your Branch') %>
```

Models:

```
Branch belongs_to :agency
Agency has_many :branches
```

I want to only show branches based on the agency selected. I'm not a jQuery whizz but I'm sure if I can add classes to the branch options based on their agency then I can use some basic javascript to achieve this.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
function getBranches(agency_id) {  
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/get_branches",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"agency_id" : agency_id},
    dataType: "html"
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#branches").html(data);
    }
  });
 }
```

Now in controller

```
def get_branches
  @branches = Agency.find(params[:agency_id]).branches
  render :partial => 'branches', :locals => {:f => f, :branches => @branches}
end
```

Now in view your view

```
<%= f.select :agency_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Agency.all, :id, :name), prompt: 'Select your Agency', :onchange => "getBranches(this.value)" %>
<div id="branches">
  <%= render :partial => 'branches', :locals => {:f => f, :branches => @branches} %>
</div>
```

The partial view _branches.html.erb

```
<%=  f.select :branch_id, options_from_collection_for_select(branches, "id", "name"), :prompt => "Select a Branch of the Agency" %>
```

In routes

```
match "/get_branches" => "<controller_name>#get_branches"
```

`controller_name` is the name of the `controller` where you define `get_branches`

Comment: I'll try this.  I assume this should be in the agency controller not the branches controller right?

Comment: I did this and changed routed and got this error `ArgumentError at /users/sign_up
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. etc etc`  I changed it from match to get and that cleared the error. I'm now getting `NameError at /users/sign_up
undefined local variable or method `f'. I suspect I need to pass the f variable into the branches partial to get it to work but I'm failing to get the syntax right

Comment: Thanks for the help Rajarshi.  I'm now getting `undefined local variable or method `branches'` Error is in the branches partial. Is the @branches from the controller not getting picked up for some reason?

Comment: Hi Craig see my update post  :locals => {:f => f, :branches => @branches}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97269/discussion-between-craig-and-rajarshi-das).